# Create a simple VOIP application

Tags: android

I want to add a feature to my existing application which is **calls over WI-FI.**

**It should be app to app calling**. I've searched the web and tried multiple solutions but I'm unable to make it work. Can someone guide me a tutorial or to link that can describe how to make calls over the wifi.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I didn't know about it. But I'm in desperate need now. I tried Sinch calling but I was struggling with some problem and I put the question on SO but didn't got a response that could solve my problem. I've searched the web as well.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip ...

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple third party exists.
1.Sinch
2.Quick Blox
if you don’t wanna build from scratch then try above third party.I have used sinch.

Comment: Could you share some code of sinch app to app calling ? I've tried sinch but there was a problem in it.

Comment: What kind of problem did u face?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493471/sinch-app-to-app-calling-sound-in-one-phone-only